# Google Classroom Api Error: Insufficient Permission

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

I have been trying to use google classroom api and get student list as shown below.

[image]

I done everything as indicated in the google classroom api documentation (added all necessary scopes in google cloud platform - oAuth consent screen, enable api for google classroom and etc.), but still getting this error below:

[image]

Can anybody help me to solve this problem I've been stuck in for a week ?

Comment: Where did you use your credentials? Have you tried checking the [Node.js quickstart for Google Classroom](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/nodejs)?

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the part of the code I notice that the Service account is not impersonating any of the user of the Admin console.

If you have set up the domain wide delegation: A service account should have domain-wide access to be able to retrieve data on behalf of a user in your domain, otherwise it acts like just another account that is trying to access its own data from Classroom.

I would advise to review the guide https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java

1. Create the credentials:

```html
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.services.sqladmin.SQLAdminScopes;

// ...

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN));
```

2. Delegate the authority and impersonate another user in your domain.

```html
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@example.org')
```

Make sure that you are impersonating a Super Admin from your organization. The service account itself can't be an administrator on the domain, but it can impersonate a domain admin, without having to store the admin's credentials.